# hide old libraries from linux system without root access

Tags: libraries

I have access to an old cluster for computations. The Operating system of the cluster is very old and outdated. Some of my codes need new libraries like `glibc-2.14` or higher to run. I found `junest` that allows us to easily have new libraries on our local account.

But the problem is that the system always uses its default libraries although I defined the PATH to new ones via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

I want to know  that:

Is there any method to make my Linux system completely blind form libraries existing in paths like `/usr/lib`and force it to use new ones, which in my case exist in the path `~/.junest/usr/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the default library rutes?

Depending on your version it could in:

**ld.so.conf** or in **ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf**

The second one is only for *libc* while the first one is for the global config where you specify which are the routes for the libraries.